# Js: Не закрывается дочернее окно

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста. 
 При нажатии на ссылку в родительском окне программно создаётся новое окно в котором создаётся кнопка "Закончить". При нажатии на эту кнопку дочернее окно должно закрываться.
Проблема: окно не закрывается. 
Вроде ерунда, а бьюсь битый час... Где в коде ошибка?

```js
var newWindow;

function OpenWin() {
  newWindow = open("", "newWindow", "location = no");

  var element = newWindow.document.createElement('button');
  element.innerHTML = 'Закончить', element.id = 'but', element.onclick =
    'CloseWin()';
  newWindow.document.body.appendChild(element);

}

function CloseWin() {
  newWindow.сlose();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #4169E1;
}

a {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="OpenWin()" id="Manjo"> Милен Демонжо </a>
<a href="#" onclick="OpenWin()" id="Pier">Пьер Ришар</a>
<a href="#" onclick="OpenWin()" id="Gosling"> Райен Гослинг</a>
```

Comment: А почему вы в `element.onclick =  'CloseWin()'`, пишите  `'CloseWin()'` в `'` - одинарных кавычках? Там передается `callback`функция или название функции без скобок и кавычек, так: `element.onclick =  CloseWin`. И да, а как он должен знать. что это именно то окно, а не следующее, которое открылось? В данном случае, будет закрываться, текущее открытое окно, а не открытое ранее, разве нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        <title> Lab 6</title>
        <style>
            body{
                background:#4169E1;
            }
            a{
                color:#FF0000;
                font-size:30px;
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#"  onclick="OpenWin()" id ="Manjo"> Милен Демонжо </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="OpenWin()" id = "Pier">Пьер Ришар</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="OpenWin()" id = "Gosling"> Райен Гослинг</a>
    </body>
    <script>
<!-- language: lang-js -->
        function OpenWin() {
            var newWindow = window.open("", "newWindow", "location = no"), element = newWindow.document.createElement('button');
            element.innerHTML = 'Закончить', element.id = 'but', element.onclick = function() {
                newWindow.close()
            };
            newWindow.document.body.appendChild(element);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: "будет закрываться, текущее открытое окно, а не открытое ранее" - перенесите декларацию `var newWindow;` внутрь `OpenWin`

Comment: @Igor, поправил. особо не хотелось с этим возиться. По этому вставил как есть.

Comment: я так и подумал: +1

Comment: Работает!!! Только мне одно не понятно, почему, если функцию выносить отдельно и правильно её записывать в onclick, она работать не будет??

Comment: @Polly, видимо окно другая уже область видимости и свой отладчик, из-за этого и не видит другие переменные и объекты, раз работает, выберите в качестве решения, ниже репутации есть галочка, нажмите на нее.